# Error "no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set"

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

Is it required to create the directory manually in nodes or will it be auto created by pv?

Here is my pv & pvc file, and I'm seeing this error

> no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set

how to resolve this?

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: zk1-pv
labels:
  type: local
spec:
storageClassName: manual
capacity:
  storage: 10Mi
accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
hostPath:
  path: "/mr/zk"

cat zk1-pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: zk1-pvc
spec:
accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
resources:
  requests:
    storage: 10Mi


kubectl describe pvc zk1-pvc
Name:          zk1-pvc
Namespace:     instavote
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
               {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"zk1-pvc","namespace":"instavote"},"spec":{"accessMo...
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
Type       Reason         Age                  From                         Message
----       ------         ----                 ----                         -------
Normal     FailedBinding  12s (x14 over 3m7s)  *persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set*
Mounted By:  zk1-745b7cbf46-lg7v9
```

Answer (score 13):

**Back to your main question**

> Is it required to create the directory manually in nodes or will it be
>   auto created by pv?

First of all, error in your output **is not related** with your question. As an answer for your question - Yes. It is crated by PV automatically.

In order to do achieve this, first you have to create `StorageClass` with `no-provisioner` as an example below

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Then you have to create `PersistentVolume` by defining this `storageClassName` and `hostPath` parameter like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: zk1-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mr/zk
```

Then you have to create PVC and Pod/Deployment as an example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: containerName
      image: gcr.io/google-containers/nginx:1.7.9
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

**NOTE:** 
Don't forget put `storageClassName: manual` parameter on both PVC and PV manifests. Otherwise they will not be able to bound to each other.

Hope it clears

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to specify `storageClassName: manual` in `PersistentVolumeClaim`.